# VB.NET 2013 Crystal Report print to printer directly without displaying

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports

I am working on VB.Net 2013 + Crystal Reports project. The task is to fetch invoice data from MSSQL as per user criteria and directly print it to a pre-defined printer. While doing that the layout of the invoice is to be used as provided by the client. So this was done in Crystal Reports.

The issue is how to print a crystal report directly to a printer without displaying any report on screen.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you please some code, where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternate solution to this question. I used Commandline Switches for Adobe Acrobat from this site:  https://www.robvanderwoude.com/commandlineswitches.php#Acrobat

Using this switch, I can send a PDF to a any physical printer. The PDF creation however is done using BullPDF printer (http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) which is a Free PDF printer application.

So the full logic is as follows:

1. Have a custom report designed per customer specifications in Crystal Reports 2013
2. Print the report from Crystal Reports to a PDF Printer using the following code:

Private Sub RunReport()
        Dim CryRpt As New ReportDocument
        Dim crTblLogInfos As New TableLogOnInfos
        Dim crTblLogInInfo As New TableLogOnInfo
        Dim crConInfo As New ConnectionInfo
        Dim crTables As Tables
        Dim crTable As Table

```
    With crConInfo
        .ServerName = ServerName
        .DatabaseName = DBName
        .UserID = UID
        .Password = Pwd
    End With

    CryRpt.Load(FPath & "rptLink.rpt")

    crTables = CryRpt.Database.Tables
    For Each crTable In crTables
        crTblLogInInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
        crTblLogInInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConInfo
        crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTblLogInInfo)
    Next
    CryRpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "Bullzip PDF Printer"
    CryRpt.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)

    OrdersLinking.DocPrinted = True
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

3. The above step would save the report as a PDF to a pre-defined folder as mentioned in Bull PDF Printer. Now send the PDF Files to the physical printer using the following commands as mentioned on https://www.robvanderwoude.com/commandlineswitches.php#Acrobat

Print a PDF file silently:

```
AcroRd32.exe /N /T PdfFile PrinterName
```

Mission Accomplished.